# Receiving a large negative number as a result when reading a small positive integer from a text file and incrementing it

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file named **counts.txt**.

This file holds one single value: the number **1**.

I want my program to read an integer from the file and increment it, but when I run the program, it is reading **-28711** rather than **1**.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int count;
    fptr = fopen("counts.txt","w+");
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&count);
    count++;
    fprintf(fptr,"%d",count);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Yes? It sounds as if it works perfectly?

Comment: Seems okay to mee too...

Comment: it just writes -28710 to the file

Comment: @user3536228 From your description, this seems to be the desired result.

Comment: Oh I see, do you mean to be '1' the initial content of the file?

Comment: Opening a file with mode `"w+"` truncates the file. Reading from it right afterward makes no sense.

Comment: maybe make a new file with the increments, and delete the current one

Comment: You did not check the return value of fscanf. Don't just ignore return values. It probly returns 0 (no items read), and the -28711 is some random value that was in the uninitialized count variable.

Comment: @unwind finally i figured out thanx for reples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
void main(void)
{
  FILE *fptr;
  int count;
  fptr = fopen("counts.txt","r+");
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&count);
  count++;

  fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET) ;   // needed to set the file pointer back to the 
                               // begining of the file
  fprintf(fptr,"%d",count);
  fclose(fptr);
}
```

But the `count.txt` file must exist before.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "r+" (read-and-write) rather than "w+" (truncate-read-and-write), as mentioned in the comments of your question.

After reading you'll want to `fseek` to the start of the file before writing, otherwise you'll just be appending numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to open file in `r+` mode since `w+` emptys the file and use fseek() to get the cursor to the begining before writing to file,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int count;
    fptr = fopen("counts.txt","r+");
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&count);
    count++;
   fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fptr,"%d",count);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, change the `fopen()` mode to `"r+"` and add `fseek()`

Other improvements added including @Bgie check for scanf()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void) {
    FILE *fptr;
    int count;
    fptr = fopen("counts.txt","r+");
    // Check fopen results
    if (fptr != NULL) {
      // Check scanf results 
      if (fscanf(fptr,"%d",&count) != 1) count = 0;
      count++;
      fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
      // Add \n to demarcate the end of the number 
      fprintf(fptr,"%d\n",count);
      fclose(fptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `"\n"` helps for without it, if the number was "-100", then "-99" overwrites the "-10" and you get "-990".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "w+" (writing with read permission) to "r+" (read with writing options) because I think w+ destroys the contents of the file.

Or try to add a fseek to put the cursor at the beginning of the file...